# Serving json file at a particular url for Android deep linking

Tags: android, json, azure, webforms, deep-linking

I'm attempting to serve a json file for Android deep linking. I created a `.well-known` folder containing an `assetlinks.json` file in the root of my web forms project. When I publish the file up to an Azure App Service and navigate to the `/.well-known/assetlinks.json` path, I get a 404 error.

Is there something more I need to do to serve a static file?

Answer (score 1):

Azure App Service does not support the static content of `.json` file by default. The solution is that add the content below to your `web.config` file under the path `wwwroot`. If there is not a `web.config` file, just create it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```